# Why buttons with the same style appear different

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, styles

[image]

**(The image is the ADD,DELETE , ADD2, DELETE2 buttons in the same space for easy comparison.)**

The current screen is the `Main(xml)` screen.

When I moved the `ADD` and `DELETE` Buttons in the image to the `ADD2` and `DELETE2` Button positions, the `styles` of the two buttons were slightly different.

The `ADD2 and DELETE2` buttons have a darker `elevation`, and the button's `border` is very transparent.

On the other hand, for the `ADD and DELETE` buttons, the `elevation` is soft.
The `border` of the button is a little more distinct.

I want the `ADD2 and DELETE2` buttons to be like the `ADD,DELETE` buttons.

What's the reason?

---

**button style**

```
<style name="AddDeleteButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/black</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/gray_500</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
</style>
```

**item_header**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/workout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="12dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll1">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_500"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            app:selectionRequired="true"
            app:checkedButton="@+id/kg">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/kg"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:theme="@style/ToggleUnitStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="KG" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lb"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:theme="@style/ToggleUnitStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="LBS"/>
        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll1">
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/AddDeleteButtonStyle"
                android:text="delete"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"/>
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/AddDeleteButtonStyle"
                android:text="add"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**main**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/item_routine_header"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="160dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/AddDeleteButtonStyle"
            android:text="delete2"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"/>
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/AddDeleteButtonStyle"
            android:text="add2"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Shadows will vary with the `View`'s location on screen, and will appear a bit darker at the bottom of it. This is due to Android's two-source shadow rendering setup that includes both an ambient light source, and a spot light source that's positioned "overhead", toward the top of the screen. Shadows at the bottom appear darker because that spot light is casting its shadow downward, out from under the `View` itself.

Comment: So is it natural for the `border` to soften and the `elevation` to darken when the button is placed at the bottom of the screen?
I would like it to appear with the `ADD,DELETE` button style.

Comment: You can lower their base elevation, but given that they're `Button`s, that's possibly going to involve fiddling with their `StateListAnimator`s. Other than than, unless you want to set custom `ViewOutlineProvider`s to lessen the shadows' resulting alpha, you can't really modify the shadows' rendering per `View` like that. Most of the renderer's settings are for the whole `Window`; e.g., the whole `Activity` or `Dialog`.

Comment: I suppose you might also be able to do something with `outlineAmbientShadowColor` and `outlineSpotShadowColor` to try to adjust the shadows on just those `Button`s, but those attributes are only available starting with API level 29, IIRC. Just FYI.

Comment: Haha. Thank you, but it's a bit difficult...